# Linked server in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, linked-server

I am working with MySQL Workbench and I want to query 2 servers at the same time. I searched and find out that the best way to proceed is to create a **linked server**.

I am wondering is it possible to create this only using workbench or MySQL server in general ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing in MySQL Workbench that lets you send a query to more than one server at a time.